# Setting up standard JavaScript prototypal inheritance within a namespace?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, namespaces, prototype-programming, hoisting

The standard prototypal inheritance in JavaScript is as follows:

```
function Animal() {
    this.legs = 0;
}
Animal.prototype.move = function () {
    alert("I'm moving!");
}

Bird.prototype = new Animal();
Bird.prototype.constructor = Bird;
function Bird() {
    this.legs = 2;
    this.wings = 2;
}
Bird.prototype.move = function () {
    alert("I'm flying!");
}
```

Does the function definition for Bird have to come after the assignment of Bird's prototype and constructor. I ask this because I'm trying to do this from within a namespace, and variable hoisting is causing my code to fail. As an example:

```
var namespace = {};
namespace.Animal = function () {
    this.legs = 0;
};
namespace.Animal.prototype.move = function () {
    alert("I'm moving!");
};

namespace.Bird.prototype = new namespace.Animal();
namespace.Bird.prototype.constructor = namespace.Bird;
namespace.Bird = function () {
    this.legs = 2;
    this.wings = 2;
};
namespace.Bird.prototype.move = function () {
    alert("I'm flying!");
};
```

Thanks to hoisting the namespace.Bird.prototype assignment statement and the namespace.Bird.prototype.constructor assignment statement fail. If I move the namespace.Bird function assignment above those two lines as shown in the following code block, however, the code seems to work.

```
namespace.Bird = function () {
    this.legs = 2;
    this.wings = 2;
};
namespace.Bird.prototype = new namespace.Animal();
namespace.Bird.prototype.constructor = namespace.Bird;
```

However, I don't know if there's a specific reason why most resources show the original order rather than having the function assignment come first.

Can someone please clarify?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason has to do with parse-time availability of functions and runtime availability of functions.

For example:

```
var afunc = asdf;
function asdf(){}
```

is the same as

```
function asdf(){} 
var afunc = asdf;
```

But,

```
var afunc = asdf;
var asdf = function(){};
```

is not the same as

```
var asdf = function(){};
var afunc = asdf;
```

Does that make sense why?

Also, the answers to this question would probably help you

[var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, that makes sense to me. That's what I was referring to with regards to hoisting. What I was wondering was whether I could switch up the order of the inheritance statements such that the function-to-variable assignment comes first (as shown in my last block of code above) so that it works within the context of a namespace. Thanks again for the response!

Comment: Your code is failing on `namespace.Bird.prototype = new namespace.Animal();` because `namespace.Bird` is not defined yet.  You could at least add `namespace.Bird={};` beforehand and that works, but not sure what it buys you.  It would make more sense to see the context you are working with.